# can I stop all email sending from a wordpress site ?where to do this wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php?

Tags: wordpress

howto close all email sending option in that word press config. should i use

```
wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php ? or where ?
 if ($this->SingleTo === true && count($toArr) > 1) {
        foreach ($toArr as $key => $val) {
          $rt = @mail($val, $this->EncodeHeader($this->SecureHeader($this->Subject)), $body, $header, $params);
          // implement call back function if it exists
          $isSent = ($rt == 1) ? 1 : 0;
          $this->doCallback($isSent,$val,$this->cc,$this->bcc,$this->Subject,$body);
        }
      }
```

will this do ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to wp-config.php, it will stop sending of all emails

```
function wp_mail()
{
    //silence is golden!!
}
```